# PostgreSQL: Using Statement Level Triggers on Views

Tags: postgresql

I am building an import/export interface on Postgres that requires semantic datamodel transformations. To facilitate the export, I created some views which provide me with a 1:1 match to my export model. In theory, I could use these views on imports as well by building a trigger structure behind it such as:

```
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON myview FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION myfunc
```

`myfunc` is an upsert function following the Schema

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE destination_table dt
    SET
    [semantic transformations]
    FROM (SELECT NEW.*) as vw_val
    LEFT JOIN value_list vl on vl.myval = vw_val.attr_val
    WHERE dt.obj_id=vw_val.obj_id;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO destination_table 
    (
    [attributes]
    )
    (
    SELECT
    [semantic transformations]
    FROM (SELECT NEW.*) as vw_val
    LEFT JOIN value_list vl on vl.myval = vw_val.attr_val
    );
    END IF;
  RETURN NEW;   
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As the interface usually alters a set of records, it would be smart to use a statement level trigger. According to [the postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html), there exists the possibility to create `BEFORE` and `AFTER` statement level triggers on views. As `NEW` and `OLD` are `NULL` on statement level, I would need a way to access all records that the interface tries to enter on my view. Is that possible?

Comment: I am afraid you can only have row level `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Comment: So the official docs are wrong?

Comment: No, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SUPPORTED-TRIGGER-TYPES